# Delete based on a distinct select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query that returns quite a few distinct, yet correct, results

```
select distinct page_id, display_id
  from display_to_page;
```

But now I'm trying to delete everything that isn't in that result set (deleting duplicates) but I'm a bit stuck.

I know I can do something like:

```
delete from display_to_page dp
(select distinct page_id, display_id
    from display_to_page) dp2 ...
```

But i'm unsure how to complete the syntax there.

How can I structure a delete that will remove anything not in that result set?

Comment: is there only 2 columns? why is there no unique constraint to prohibit the duplication?

Comment: I'm trying to create a unique index right now, and it fails because there are duplicates. So I'm trying to delete all duplicates so that I can create the unique index

Comment: If you use `ALTER IGNORE TABLE ADD UNIQUE INDEX...` it will create the unique index and remove all the duplicates.

Comment: OK, then the solution suggested by Gordon Linoff will work. nb: `alter ignore` might not work in your version of MySQL

Comment: @Used_By_Already Yeah, just discovered that it's been removed in 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two columns in the table, then the easiest way is probably truncate/reload:

```
create temporary table temp_pd as
    select distinct page_id, display_id
    from display_to_page;

truncate table display_to_page;

insert into display_to_page (page_id, display_id)
    select page_id, display_id
    from temp_pd;
```

Be sure to copy the table before trying this on your data!

Comment: there actually is another column called active but still should work

Comment: @TomN. Is that column the same for all the duplicates

Comment: No it's not. The unique index is only on the 2 above, but the active column holds 0 or 1 for each